# Apptainer blocks during file copy in a multistage build

Tags: apptainer

I have an apptainer recipe like

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: gcc:latest
Stage: devel

%files
    ~/.ssh/known_hosts /root/.ssh/
    ~/.ssh/id_rsa      /root/.ssh/

%post
    apt update -y && apt install -y --no-install-recommends libhts-dev && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    git clone git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/myutils.git && cd myutils && make

# Install binaries into the final image
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:latest
Stage: final

# install binaries from stage devel
%files from devel
    /myutils/utility    /usr/bin
```

The stage `devel` runs fine and generates a small binary (53648B), but the `final` stage, that just have to get a base container and copy a file, gets blocked at the copy step. It didn't finished after a whole night.

Is there something obvious I'm not doing well?